# Find string then return different row value Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, row

I've been trying to figure out how to search for a `string`, and once that `string` is found look at the cell that is `9 rows` below it.  The below 3 lines I copied out of the code, the entire code is below as well.

First, I read in `TFile` column B.

Second, I read in `Detail2` this is a large file but I only want the `string` that is inside cell `A1`. I make `Detail2` into a `string`.  The variable window shows `Detail2` as a `string` and shows the string as `A118`.

Third, Result uses TFile header `NAME` to find string `Detail2 (A118)`. And, it does find `Detail2(A118)`. So, up to this point everything is working, I just need to figure out how to now look at the `cell 9 rows` below `Detail2 (A118)`. Is this even possible to do right in result line?

Here's a picture of TFile.  The header is NAME and Detail2 (A118) is seen at the top.  Once the script locates Detail2 I need it to locate the value 9 rows below it so that would be AN000.2000.

[image: TFile]

```
   TFile=pd.read_excel(TT, usecols="B")

   Detail2=pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols="A",nrows=1,header=None,squeeze=True).str.slice(start=28,stop=-2).to_string(index=False).strip()

   result=TFile['Name'].str.contains(Detail2)




import openpyxl as xl 
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell



input_dir = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NNM'
Summary = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\Summary.xlsx'
TT = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\TT.xlsx'
Dwell = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\Dwell.xlsx'
newFile = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\Comparison.xlsx'




files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".xlsx")]

i=0

wb3=xlsxwriter.Workbook(newFile)
ws3=wb3.add_worksheet('Comparison')


for row_num in range(1,30):
    ws3.write_formula(row_num - 1, 5,
                            '=ABS(C%d - E%d)' % (row_num, row_num))
    
for row_num in range(1,30):
    ws3.write_formula(row_num - 1, 10,
                            '=ABS(H%d - J%d)' % (row_num, row_num)) 
    
for row_num in range(1,30):
    ws3.write_formula(row_num - 1, 15,
                            '=ABS(N%d - O%d)' % (row_num, row_num))     
    

ws3.write_row("A1:Q1", ['TNAME','Start Segment','Start Chainage(ft)','Start Segment','Start Chainage(ft)','Start Chainage Difference(ft)','End Segment','End Chainage(ft)','End Segment','End Chainage(ft)','End Chainage Difference(ft)','Stops','Stops','Distance','Distance','Distance Difference (ft)','Comments'])
ws3.set_column(1, 17, 35)
wb3.close()
 
wb3 = xl.load_workbook(newFile) 
ws3 = wb3.worksheets[0]
 
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(Summary) 
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[1]
 
 
for file in files: 
   input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
   wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
   ws1=wb1.worksheets[0]
    
 
   Stop1 = pd.read_excel(file,usecols = "F",squeeze = True)
   counts1 = Stop1.value_counts()
   z1 = counts1[0]/2
    
   Stop2 = pd.read_excel(Dwell,usecols = "A",squeeze = True)
   Detail=pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols="A",nrows=1,header=None,squeeze=True).str.slice(start=28,stop=-2).to_string(index=False).strip()
   counts2 = Stop2.str.match(Detail).sum()

 
   TFile=pd.read_excel(TT, usecols="B")

   Detail2=pd.read_excel(input_file, usecols="A",nrows=1,header=None,squeeze=True).str.slice(start=28,stop=-2).to_string(index=False).strip()

   result=TFile['NAME'].str.contains(Detail2)

    
   ws3[f'A{i+2}']=ws1['A1'].value[28:]
   ws3[f'D{i+2}']=ws1['B4'].value
   ws3[f'E{i+2}']=ws1['D4'].value
   ws3[f'I{i+2}']=ws1['B'][-1].value
   ws3[f'J{i+2}']=ws1['D'][-1].value
   ws3[f'O{i+2}']=ws1['E'][-1].value 
   ws3[f'N{i+2}']=ws2[f'I{i+6}'].value   
   ws3[f'M{i+2}']=z1
   ws3[f'L{i+2}']=counts2
   
   i += 1
   
   wb3.save(newFile)
```

Comment: add sample input and expected output

Comment: I have added a screen shot of TFile, and what I need out of it.

Comment: Looking for any suggestions